# Configuring several subnets on a single IP

Tags: ip, subnet

Is it possible (and correct) to configure one single IP with several subnets?

For example:

```
ip               subnet
172.30.176.17    172.30.176.0/23
172.30.176.17    172.30.176.0/24
```

Is this a valid and sound configuration?

Comment: Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes, on Linux with multiple route tables, it might even be useful.  Is it 'correct'.  Almost never.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it's technically possible in some implementations, but there's really no good reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? You can configure multiple networks with one IP, but don't forget about route metrics (smaller network have better metric)